# How to add margin right and left of dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog

I want the dialog doesn't stretch to fit width of display screen. I want the dialog had about  90% of screen width and center its.
How can I do it?

Thank you very much ^^

Comment: Can we see what code you are trying to open dialog?

Answer (score 9):

You can give style with below attributes to get dialog size as percentage of screen.

```
<style name="YourDialogTheme">
<item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">90%</item>
<item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">90%</item>
</style>
```

Then Apply theme as below in your dialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.YourDialogTheme));
```

See [windowMinWidthMinor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowMinWidthMinor)
and [windowMinWidthMajor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowMinWidthMajor)

Comment: Glade to know. You can also accept answer as its works for you.

Answer (score 4):

For the easiest way you can do something like this:

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/defaultMargin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/defaultMargin">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</RelativeLayout>
```

also, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39618516/android-how-to-set-dialogs-outer-margin) can referred

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example to set margins in dialogs

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
// ... 

// e.g. top + right margins: 
dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.RIGHT);
WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
layoutParams.x = 100; // right margin
layoutParams.y = 170; // top margin
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);

// e.g. bottom + left margins: 
dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.LEFT);
WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
layoutParams.x = 100; // left margin
layoutParams.y = 170; // bottom margin
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I try it before and if I want to set layout margin for only left and right. What gravity I have to set ?. And I should use this code before or after dialog.show() and dialog.setContentview() function